# Force exe application to run in foreground in Jenkins/Python

Tags: python, jenkins, ibm-doors, background-foreground

I have a Jenkins job that executes a python script and that python script calls IBM Doors.

In Jenkins the python script is executed like this:

```
def execute = bat(script: "python -u MyScript.py", returnStdout: true)
echo execute
```

In the python script, IBM Doors is started like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['pathToDoors\\doors.exe', '-osUser'])
Doors = Dispatch('Doors.Application')
```

After Doors is running I'm executing some dxl scripts using:

```
Doors.runFile('MyScript.dxl')
```

The issue is that Doors is always running in background when I start the Jenkins job. The problem with this is that I am not able to see any error messages that Doors might show regarding the dxl script execution.
Doors is only started in background, with no GUI when the python script is executed from Jenkins. If I execute that py from the PowerShell/CommandPrompt on the Jenkins slave then Doors is running in foreground with the GUI.

My question is:
Is it possible to force exe applications to run in foreground (with GUI) when the python scripts are executed from Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

You can start DOORS in batch mode and give the file to execute as a parameter (`doors.exe -batch path\\to\\dxl\\file.dxl`). Then DOORS will present its messages on its STDOUT/STDERR that you can catch from your `subprocess`.

Comment: Using my method with subprocess.Popen and Doors dispatch I'm also using Doors.result to communicate with Doors (transmit and receive data). How can I transmit/recieve data to/from Doors if I implement your method?

Comment: Usually, I prefer to transfer data using files. this has proven to be the most stable communication method. your python program could e.g. create a temporary directory, the directory name is transferred via an environment variable beforve you start DOORS and your DXL script could create response files in this directory or read files from there

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins jobs are run in whichever context Jenkins is running in. This means that, if your Jenkins agent is running as a service, it (and any processes it starts) will run in the background.

If you want your jobs to run in the foreground, you need to run the Jenkins agent in the foreground (i.e. as the logged-in user), rather than as a service.

Comment: I'm currently launching the agent via SSH. Which launch method would be suitable for my issue?